# How to restore sanity while I am playing as a Maxwell?

Tags: dont-starve

While I am playing as a Maxwell I want to create as many puppets as possible but the black area is covering my sanity points. Is there a way to get rid of this black area? I know that I can kill puppets, but I am wondering if there is such an item which will remove that black area as like booster pack does to health.

Comment: You can't. Sanity lost through the puppets can only return by having them die/disappear. Sanity overall can't be improved either.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray If you know the answer to a question, actually post it as an answer rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to increase your maximum sanity on Maxwell. The only character who can do that is WX-78 depending on his upgrades. [Source](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Sanity)

There is no way to regain the sanity sacrificed with the Codex Umbra safe for removing the shadow-creatures summoned by it.

If you really want to get your sanity up again I guess you could use the console command  `c_setsanit​y(percent)`, percent being fractal, meaning 90% = 0.9. I don't know what happens if you set a higher percentage than currently possible due to the Codex Umbra as it is undocumented and I don't have time to try it out myself at the moment. [This](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Console/Commands) site provides detailed instructions on how to use the command console in case anyone is interested.